# How to make Expandable listView expand with animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, expandablelistview

I'm trying to animate the way the expandable listView expands, but I can't find anything on the web on how to do that except for this: https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView/  and I'm not that professional so I can't understand how to implement it to my activity. Please if you know tell me how to add it my activity or another way to do so, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apply animation on `OnGroupClickListener`. You could do something like -

```
listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            if (listView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) 
                listView.collapseGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);
            else 
                listView.expandGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);
            return true;
        }

    });
```

[Link](https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView) to `AnimatedExpandableListView` library.

Comment: what is collapse/expandGroupWithAnimation?

Comment: how to add the AnimatedExpandableListView library to my app?